# Crop Image using Javascript (Croppie)

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, crop, croppie

I am trying to crop an image to cicle using the [Croppie Library](https://github.com/Foliotek/Croppie/blob/master/index.html)

I have tried to use their functions to return base64 encoded image.
And it return a base64 code but without the image:
Here is my code:

```
<div id="vanilla-demo"></div>
 </div>
<img id="myImage" src="">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="croppie.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">


        var vanilla = new Croppie(document.getElementById('vanilla-demo'), {
            viewport: { width: 200, height: 200 , type:'circle'},
            boundary: { width: 400, height: 400 },
            showZoom: false
        });
        vanilla.bind('dac.jpg');
            vanilla.result('canvas','original').then(function (src) {
                    console.log(src);
                    $('#myImage').attr('src', src);
            });

</script>
```

Comment: What is not working ?

Comment: Potentially dumb comment but you included the `croppie.css` as they specified correct?

Comment: Yes its included  <link rel="stylesheet" href="croppie.css" />

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm one of the creators of Croppie.  With a quick glance at your code, I'd say that your croppie isn't bound yet.  The bind method returns a Promise that you'll need to wait to be resolved.  The Promise waits for the image to load and all of the initialization logic to finish on the Croppie.

I would change your bind and result logic to do the following instead:

```
vanilla.bind('dac.jpg').then(function() {
    vanilla.result('canvas','original').then(function (src) {
        console.log(src);
        $('#myImage').attr('src', src);
    });
});
```

Comment: Hey Dustin! Thanks for creating this plugin. I pretty much have figure everything out except how to pass the cropped photo be be stored on the server. Can't seem to find anything on how to do that anywhere.

Comment: @xxSithRagexx you should probably ask this as a question of its own, but I was able to send the base64 string to a google sheet using a google apps script with a POST and I think I did with a GET too from the client side. It was super picky though.